# cy.fit() does not work immediately, it needs timeout to fit the graph. Cytoscape js

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, graph, synchronization, cytoscape.js

So after initializing the graph, I want to make it fit to its div by using `cy.fit()`. I have done this:

```
var cy = cytoscape({
        container: document.getElementById("cy"),
        elements: {
            nodes: nodes,
            edges: edges
        },
        layout: {
            name: 'dagre',
            
        },
          
        style: [
            {
              selector: 'node',
              css: { 
                'label': 'data(id)',
                'background-color': '#808080'
             }
 
          ]
      });
```

So after this part if I do

```
cy.fit()
```

It does not work. But if I do this:

```
setTimeout(() => { 
        cy.fit();
    },1000);
```

It works. However first the unfitted graph gets displayed and then after 1000 ms the proper graph fit gets displayed. Thus When a page is loaded, it looks like the graph is written twice.

How can I fix this? Is there a way to initialize the graph with this 'fit' option? Or any other way to fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cytoscape.js deals with this via [cy.ready()](https://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.ready). Just use it like this:

```
var cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById("cy"),
  elements: {
    nodes: nodes,
    edges: edges
  },
  layout: {
    name: 'dagre',
  },
  style: [{
    selector: 'node',
    css: {
      'label': 'data(id)',
      'background-color': '#808080'
    }
  }]
});

cy.ready(function() {
  cy.fit();
});
```

Also, you can just use the layout option `fit` for this:

```
layout: { name: 'dagre', fit: true }
```

Comment: So the fit option in the layout is present but it doesn't do anything. And I looked at cy.ready() and saw that it indeed seem like what I need however I couldn't make it work either. But your answer is what I was looking for it seems so.

Comment: I am putting "cy.fit()" inside a setTimeout method and the cy.ready() method. Even though the inside content is the same, the timeout one works but the other one does not. @Stephan T.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), maybe that way we can work out a better solution